# Navigation doesn't look right in IE (CSS problem?)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Can somebody tell me why the navigation (about, snow areas, condition alerts) doesn't work in IE?

http://snow.solspot.com/conditions/north-america/us-east/vermont/okemo/

I have been trying to fix this for days now...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, specifically? The navigation does seem to work, it's just not very pretty.

Comment: what version(s) of IE do you have a problem with. Please be specific about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `<a id="dd1" style="width: 170px;">` this inline style is creating the huge gap between the elements. I removed this in IE8's developer tools and it looked similar to how it appears in Chrome.

Remove this width from the inline style on each of the links.:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of this error on IE?

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.2) Timestamp: Wed, 19 Jan 2011 04:52:03 UTC


Message: 'this.tabs[...]' is null or not an object Line: 26 Char: 4 Code: 0 URI: http://snow.solspot.com/wp-content/themes/solspot_snow/js/mootools-tabs.js


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 3086 Char: 3 Code: 0 URI: http://snow.solspot.com/wp-content/themes/solspot_snow/js/mootools-1.2.4-core.js


Message: Object expected
Line: 61
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://snow.solspot.com/
```

Please check. Maybe it will point you to the right direction on how to fix it.